# download file on jquery ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, download

I'm creating a word document on server side on ajax event and as response if there were no errors I would like to push it download. Is it possible with jquery ajax? My code looks at this moment as it follows

```
                $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: 'docsx.php',
                       data: $("#edit_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                       success: function(data)
                       {
                        **here should be fired the download** // show response from the php script.
                       },
                       error:function(){

                           alert('Es gibt ein Fehler bei Daten übetragung!');

                        }
                     });
```

Comment: You could just redirect them to a page that'll force the download (by setting the appropriate headers). Another option is to use [this](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/), but unfortunately it's not exactly ready. It seems that they're still experimenting with it.

Comment: thanks for the feedback I have been previously taking a look on your suggested link but was not working on my case, however your first suggest is making what I want. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've done this myself once: You can generate the file in php, put it on your server somewhere, and then return the path to your script. Next, create a hidden iframe and call a simple script that just reads the file and returns it with the appropriate headers set to force the download. Result will be a forced download without page refresh.

Comment: in my case on debian environment this snippet is doing till now the appropriate job   window.location.href ='to_download.docx';

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fire downloads using javascript. Simply don't use AJAX for this purpose. Use a standard form submission to the `docsx.php` script:

```
<form action="docsx.php" method="post">
    ... some input fields

    <input type="submit" value="Download" />
</form>
```

Comment: the job is a bit more complicated I have a jquery ui dialog box and inside on button events I fire lot of tasks and I don't want to push the user to to jump out from the dialog box.

Comment: You will not jump out of the dialog box if your server side script directly streams the file to the response using the `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foobar.txt` header.This will directly prompt the user to select a location to save the file to on his computer without navigating away from the current page.

Comment: okay thanks I'm going to give a try with it, but what about this  window.location.href ='to_download.docx'. The document is getting created and than I'm using this snippet to download as ajax response. There would doubts in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div id="Status_Update" title="Update your Status Here">
    <form method="post" action="update_status.php?<?php echo(SID); ?>" name="Status_form" id="Status_form">
      <span id="sprytextfield1">
      <label for="text1"></label>
      <label for="textfield6"></label>
      <textarea class="ns_tb" name="status_update_box" cols="60" placeholder="What is on your mind" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; border: thin solid #0C0; border-radius:9px;"></textarea>
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
      <input type="submit" name="status_update_button" id="button" value="Post" style=" background-color:#0C0; border-radius:9px;)"/>
      <a href="#" id="hide_status_box" tittle="Hide the Status Comment Box">hide</a>
    </form>
  </div>
```